# how to send data to EventGrid from .Net core app using Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-eventgrid, azure-identity

I have a .net core app, which is trying to send the data to eventGrid topic . Using `Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid` Nuget to send the same. I am creating a instance of  `EventGridClient`

```
new EventGridClient(new TopicCredentials(configuration.Key)).
```

I am trying for Identity approach. but the issue is, not getting any overload which accepts `TokenCredential` . Neither in *`EventGridClient`* nor in *`TopicCredentials`*. Event checked in the MSDN suggested Nuget `Azure.Messaging.EventGrid`, same case here as well.

how to handle this secnario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available as of [version 4.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid/4.5.0) of the new Azure.Messaging.EventGrid library. It is not available in Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.

[Usage example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/eventgrid/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid#authenticate-using-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Yes , it the latest release. i think this will be answer to my issue. More over Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid need to upgraded by Azure.Messaging.EventGrid

Comment: Sorry, I mean that this functionality is available in the Azure.Messaging.EventGrid library, which is a different library than Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid. Going forward, Azure.Messaging.EventGrid will be getting new functionality while Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid will only get critical bug fixes.

Comment: Right, but the Version mentioned above released on July 20, but i posted on 19th, As i checked the Azure.Messaging.EventGrid as well which was not released by that time.

Answer (score 0):

Azure EventGrid [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-event-grid) Managed Identities. The feature is currently in preview.

Support for authenticating with Azure.Identity will be added to the SDK after this feature is generally available (GA).

You will need to use the [AzureKeyCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.eventgrid-readme#creating-and-authenticating-eventgridpublisherclient) for now.

Comment: I trust you more than myself